# CSS Elements in columns are under the upper border while scale transforming

Tags: html, css

I have 4 columns of images using `column-count` and I want them to scale on mouse hover.

The first column works fine but the next three will be under the upper border while transforming.

I tried all kinds of margins and padding and I also tried `z-index` but it didn't work.

Here's live [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PyQt/w7n6yaeh/1/)

Code:

```css
.content{
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: black;
}

.photos img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.photos {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px;
}

li img {
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
}


li img:hover {
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <ul class="photos">
        <li>
            <img src="https://syndlab.com/files/view/5db9b150252346nbDR1gKP3OYNuwBhXsHJerdToc5I0SMLfk7qlv951730.jpeg">
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/t2UjB23Xy8xLCPcwavD_5pqDWQH8wx1tOggm85KZq22oyODukZGZyMDIfGHwIKyZj1U4JeAzn3t5bkgPXcV8pJ60udJ1eQ">
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src="https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/bavarian_landscape_515460.jpg">
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src="https://cdn-ep19.pressidium.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/16-9-original-1.jpg">
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why using column? simply make all the image in a row

Comment: I have more than 4 images and they all are different sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to flexbox and achieve the same behavior with no problem.

Just adjust you CSS like this:

```
.photos {
    display: flex;
}

li {
  width: 25%;
}
```

Here's a working live Codepen: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/jObWjLm

## Update:

Ok so if you want to achieve what you post in the comment below I suggest you to move to a pure CSS Mansory approach. Here's the code:
Remove the column management and the list (ul/li) and use divs:

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="item">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/600x620.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/t2UjB23Xy8xLCPcwavD_5pqDWQH8wx1tOggm85KZq22oyODukZGZyMDIfGHwIKyZj1U4JeAzn3t5bkgPXcV8pJ60udJ1eQ">
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      <img src="https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/bavarian_landscape_515460.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ep19.pressidium.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/16-9-original-1.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ep19.pressidium.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/16-9-original-1.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ep19.pressidium.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/16-9-original-1.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      <img src="https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/bavarian_landscape_515460.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      <img src="https://cdn-ep19.pressidium.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/16-9-original-1.jpg">
   </div>
   <span class="item break"></span>
   <span class="item break"></span>
   <span class="item break"></span>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS Code:

```
.content {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  /* Your container needs a fixed height, and it 
   * needs to be taller than your tallest column. */
  height: 960px;
  
  /* Optional */
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 40px auto;
  counter-reset: items;
}

.item {
  width: 24%;
  /* Optional */
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

/* Re-order items into 3 rows */
.item:nth-of-type(4n+1) { order: 1; }
.item:nth-of-type(4n+2) { order: 2; }
.item:nth-of-type(4n+3) { order: 3; }
.item:nth-of-type(4n)   { order: 4; }

/* Force new columns */
.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0;
  margin: 0;
  content: "";
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

img:hover {
    transition: .5s;
    transform: scale(1.12);
}
```

Here's the working live Codepen: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/MWayKaq

And [here](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/masonry-with-css/) the reference where I get this kind of approach.

Comment: It's a great solution but I didn't use it cause I have images with different sizes and ratios and so the grid would be deformed. Columns don't have this problem, but maybe there is a way to do it with flex?

Comment: @SerhiiStets in my codepen the images don't seem to be stretched, please have a look

Comment: Yea, but the problems begin when we start to add more images and want to remain these 4 columns with the grid type system. If we use [flex here](https://codepen.io/serhiistets/pen/ExVKYqo) it will make a row with the height of the biggest image. Now with [columns](https://jsfiddle.net/PyQt/w7n6yaeh/4/), it would wrap all images with the same gap between them making a grid. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: @SerhiiStets yes you can with flexbox, using a "pure css masonry approach", I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the columns is that the browser is "confused" and thinks the non-first images are more down below.

I found 2 possibilities to make this work, first my favorite: `display: flex;`

```css
.content{
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

.photos img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.photos {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

.photos li{
  flex-basis: 25%;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

li img {
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
}


li img:hover {
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    transform: scale(1.12);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <ul class="photos">
        <li>
            <img src="https://syndlab.com/files/view/5db9b150252346nbDR1gKP3OYNuwBhXsHJerdToc5I0SMLfk7qlv951730.jpeg">
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/t2UjB23Xy8xLCPcwavD_5pqDWQH8wx1tOggm85KZq22oyODukZGZyMDIfGHwIKyZj1U4JeAzn3t5bkgPXcV8pJ60udJ1eQ">
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src="https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/bavarian_landscape_515460.jpg">
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src="https://cdn-ep19.pressidium.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/16-9-original-1.jpg">
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

the other possibilities using your column settings are dased around adding `position: absolute` to `.photos img` or `float: left` to `.photos`.

**Edit:** I see that Alessio created his answer while I was working on mine and he also uses float. Please accept his answer as the working one if you go with the `float` solution.